# How do I add active class to this menu item?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add an active class to this submenu item.

**Menu item-**

```
<ul class="mainnav ">
  <li class="active"><a href="/Home/Index"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-upload" id="upload-card"></i></a></li>
  <li>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>                               
  </li>
</ul>
```

There is already `active` class is added on first li item. I am trying to remove this class from siblings on click of current active menu item.

**This is what I tried-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('ul .mainnav > li').click(function () {
             $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').addClass('active');
         });    
     });
</script>
```

But this is not working.

Thanks for help.

Comment: When you click an anchor with a href, doesn't that redirect you to another page ?

Comment: @adeneo, Believing it to work on non-redirecting anchors only now.

Comment: Change it to `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
   $('.mainnav li').click(function () {
         $(this).siblings().removeClass('active')
         $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Working example. http://jsfiddle.net/CgSwt/